# Smooth scrolling won't scroll smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read a ton of topics on smooth scrolling, and I can't get them to work.
I was thinking to write the code in "js/script.js" folder-file, and copied the "script.js" link to the bottom of the main page. Do I have to write the script for smooth scroll in the main index.html? I want to keep that page as clean and concise as possible, hence the outsourcing.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $(this.href);
if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 700);
}
});
```

Doesn't really matter if it's this one or any other awesome piece of scrolling code I found online, my test page still scrolls like a Windows 98 PC version.

I believe to have properly defined `class` with each `href`, like so:

```
        `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#page-top">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#about">About us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>`
```

Couly you please help me?

PS: Is JS = jQuery?

Comment: do you have large images on page?

Comment: I have 0 images on the page. The only external thing is a glyphon

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a class for the action like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.yourClass').on('click', function(event) {
        ...
    }
)};
```

And in your HTML:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="yourClass" href="#contact">Contact</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Also, jQuery is a libary to extend JavaScript. So make sure you have included the latest jQuery in your index.html

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```